# Recovering data from a (possibly) damaged and encrypted drive

Tags: data-recovery

I was using Ubuntu 17.10 (not installing packages, just web browsing), when I realized I could not write any data to the disk.  If I typed `touch filename` I received this error (paraphrasing) `Unable to write to a read-only filesystem`.

I then shutdown the system.  Now, on boot, I can no longer reach the grub screen.  I can't get past the motherboard's disk selection screen.  Occasionally, I'll see an error related to UEFI appear but it disappears to quickly to read the full message.

The (possibly) damaged drive is still listed as a block device.

If I boot to a LiveUSB and attempt to mount the filesystem `mount /dev/sda /mnt/corrupted` I get the error "can't read superblock on /dev/sda".

If it matters, I don't need a full disk recovery.  I only need my `Documents` folder from the drive.  I'm fine with losing everything else.

Comment: I think your disk is dead! Not sure but try testdisk... from a liveCD session

Comment: read your SMART data first; it reads data from the circuits on the drive so doesn't do any harm (works with drive unmounted) and gives a status of your drive, and how dead/close-to-death it is.  `smartctl` or your favorite alternative.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the help but its totally dead!  Oh well.